# All of a sudden error in google colabatory making error with print

Tags: python

I've been making this book that records user data (which I'm new to coding so I am trying to figure out how to do such) and I've encountered a random error making my print come up as a syntax error or something along the lines. Heres my code:

```
import time 
def function_1():
  print("The time of code execution begin is : ", end ="") 
  print(time.ctime()) 
  var_1 = input("Enter Username ")
  var_2 = input("Enter Password")
  if "l1k3!" in var_1 and "Vmmk1" in var_2:
      print("Valid")
      print("Welcome back")
      print("Security Measure 2")
      x = int(input("Enter Code"))
      if x == 4465:
        print("Secuirty Measures Complete")
        time.sleep(5) ; print("Booting up Book")
        time.sleep(1) ; print(".")
        time.sleep(1) ; print(".")
        time.sleep(1) ; print(".")
        time.sleep(2)  ; print("Enter something to be recorded.")
        time.sleep (2) ; bazooka = input("Enter Here : ")
        print("Do NOT restart code unless your going to use something else to be recorded.")
#this is where im encountering the error
        z = int(input("Type 7 here if you want to now. Leave blank to continue normally.")
          if z == 7
            print("I need to put it in maunually.")
          else:
            print("Loading...")
        time.sleep(3)print("Thank you for recording in this book.")
        time.sleep(1)print("First Recording:It is currently 9:19:24:22 2020 that this is being recorded")
        time.sleep(1)print(bazooka)

        time.sleep(5) ; return
      else:
        print("Nah fam try again")
  else:
      print("Invalid, Restart Code") 

function_1()
```

Anything helps, thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the error you are getting?

Comment: You should specify which statement(s) get the error.  But looking near the end of the program sample here, you are missing some statement-separating semicolons.  That being said, putting multiple statements on one line is frowned upon in python.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you forgot to write a colon at the end of the if (if z==7:)

Answer (score 0):

Its because its not'z' thats why. Thanks for the help tho